# ASP.NET Session and LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, session, linq-to-entities

I have a question regarding a project I am working on at the moment.

I have this code:

```
 var query = from user in dwe.UsersTable
                        where user.LoginName.Equals(usernameBox.Text) && user.Password.Equals(pwBox.Text)
                        select user;

        if (query.Count() == 1)
        {
            Session["User"] = usernameBox.Text;                     
            Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            LabelError.Text = "Error try again";
        }
    }
```

In my "UsersTable" I have a coulmn named "UserID". **I want to** send the "userID" as a session to the redirected page (Edit.aspx) the userID must equal the result of comparression between Username and password.

Comment: [Use `Any` instead of `Count`](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/04/21/38598/)

Comment: It is bad practice to store users' passwords in plaintext in the database.  You should consider hashing their password and storing that instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you just need to write down

```
var query = (from user in dwe.UsersTable 
                        where user.LoginName.Equals(usernameBox.Text) && 
                        user.Password.Equals(pwBox.Text)
                         select user).FirstOrDefault();

if(query!=null)
{
   Session["User"] = query.UserID; 
   Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx"); 
}
else
{
   LabelError.Text = "Error try again";
}
```

No need to write donw code you have which use Count method instead of this just make use Of `FirstOrDefault` will give you the result easily.

Comment: Pranay Rana, It works thanks alot for the quick answer and help! You saved me alot of time

Comment: how do i make it as accepted answer? it's my first time in the website :/

Answer (score 3):

```
var query = from user in dwe.UsersTable
            where user.LoginName.Equals(usernameBox.Text) 
                  && user.Password.Equals(pwBox.Text)
            select user;

// get user from query
// If SingleOrDefault is not supported (<4.0) use FirstOrDefault instead. 
// Thanks Tim Schmelter
var user = query.SingleOrDefault(); 

if (user != null)
{
    Session["UserID"] = user.UserID;                 
    Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx");
}
else
{
    LabelError.Text = "Error try again";
}
```

Comment: Note that `SingleOrDefault` is not supported in `Linq-To-Entities` 3.5, use `FirstOrDefault` then.

Comment: thanks alot flem, I tryed both your answer and Paranay and it works fine here! thumbs up :-)
Cheers